# Can I carry more than one variable in an href?

Tags: php, html

I'm carrying one variable in "reserva" wich I later I use $_GET('reserva'), but I also need another one of the rows,how could I do it?

```
<?php 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['idps'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Descrição'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dia'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dataini'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['datafim'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['tblstaff_idPrestador'];?></td>

  
        <td><a href='marcar.php?reserva=<?php echo $row['idps'];?>'>Marcar</a></td>
        
        </tr>

    <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: `&othervar=something` maybe.  Or better build the string with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can append multiple values in a GET request using `&`:

```
<a href='marcar.php?reserva=<?php echo $row['idps'];?>&key=value'>Marcar</a>
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

as [@raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229023/raina77ow) pointed out, be aware that `&` is a "reserved" char, so if your string contains that, you have to encode it, and for that, in PHP you have the function [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: ... just be sure it's urlencoded, just in case. ) This doesn't look really bothersome here, as it seems to be a primary key column anyway.

Comment: @raina77ow added

Comment: Thank you, very helpful it's working nicely now